# "Attribute is protected within this context" with inheritance and .h and .cpp files

Tags: c++, file, inheritance

I'm trying to code a game with Irrlicht, but I got stuck with this problem meanwhile I was separating the code into .h and .cpp files.

The main error in the compiler is 'node is protected within this context". 
Node is an attribute of "GameObjectOverworld", and was invoked from "Player" (GameObjectOverworld child class)

This worked fine until I separated the code in .h and .cpp files.

The GameObjectOverworld.h

```
#ifndef __GAMEOBJECTOVERWORLD_H__
#define __GAMEOBJECTOVERWORLD_H__

#include <irrlicht.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "GameObject.h"

class GameObjectOverWorld : public GameObject{
    protected:
        scene::ISceneNode* node = nullptr; 
    public: 
        GameObjectOverWorld() {}
        core::vector3df getPosition(){return node->getPosition();}
};

#endif
```

The player.h

```
#ifndef __PLAYER_H__
#define __PLAYER_H__

#include <irrlicht.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "GameObject.h"
#include "GameObjectOverworld.h"

using namespace irr;
using namespace core;
using namespace scene;
using namespace video;
using namespace io;
using namespace gui;
class Player : public GameObjectOverWorld{
    private: 

        std::string name =""; 
        float speed = 15.0f; 
    public:
        Player() = default;
        void addPlayerModel(ISceneManager* smgraux, IVideoDriver* driveraux){}
        void move (char axis, int direction, float frameDeltaTime){}
};
#endif
```

And player.cpp (the one which sends the error)

```
#include "Player.h"

void addPlayerModel(ISceneManager* smgraux, IVideoDriver* driveraux){
    Player::node = smgraux->addCubeSceneNode(10.0f, 0, 0, core::vector3df(15.0f, 0.0f, 45.0f), core::vector3df(0, 0, 0), core::vector3df(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f));

    if (node)
    {

        node->setMaterialTexture(0, driveraux->getTexture("Materials/madero.jpg"));
        node->setMaterialFlag(video::EMF_LIGHTING, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: Six `using namespace` declarations? Wow...

Comment: I'm trying to get used to Irrlicht, but yes, that's a lot

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to link the method `addPlayerModel` to the class:

Change:

```
void addPlayerModel(ISceneManager* smgraux, IVideoDriver* driveraux)
```

To

```
void Player::addPlayerModel(ISceneManager* smgraux, IVideoDriver* driveraux)
```

Also change `Player::node` to `this->node` because your 'node' attribute is not static.

Comment: Thanks! It worked, but, can I get more insight on why should be this way?

Comment: @JoseManuelPalau Member functions declared outside a class must have the `Class::` prefix.

Comment: @JoseManuelPalau This might help to clarify: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_class_member_functions.htm